# How do I get a JLabel linked to a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I would like to find out how I can link a JLabel to a JButton, so that when ever the button is hovered over, a piece of text appears. Sort of like a tool tip, indicating what this button does before it's clicked.

Comment: Swing tool tip - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why ask for something "sort of like a tool tip" when you can use just that, a tool tip? Simply set the JButton's tool tip text via the JComponent `setToolTipText(...)` method (which JButton inherits) and you're there!

```
myButton.setToolTipText("Foo");
```